# installation of xampp

Tags: xampp

i have just installed xampp on my window 7 32bit OS.
The problem is that the php which came with xampp is not working properly ie;I am not able to display even the traditional "hello world" in the browser.
I read the "Readme.txt" file which came with the installation and it read that my version of xampp supports windows 7 but it didn't specify if it is a windows 32bit or 64bit.
When I visited apachefriends.org the site claims they do not support windows 7. the info on apachefriends.org reads

> " At the moment there are four XAMPP versions: a version for Linux
>   systems (tested for Ubuntu, SuSE, RedHat, Mandrake and Debian), a
>   version for Windows 2000, 2003, XP and Vista beta version for Solaris
>   SPARC (developed and tested under Solaris 8),and a beta version for
>   Mac OS X."

If anyone has installed xampp on windows 7 32bit and it is working fine.Please provide a link so i can install it.
Thank you.

Comment: post your _hello world_ code and specify the error that's being reported..

Comment: my hello world script is displayed below :
<?php
echo"hello world";
?>

The script is saved as hello.php
when i test the script in mozilla firefox nothing is displayed on the screen.
when i test it in opera the script is displayed back to me not the output,hello world.
I suspected it's a windows 7 compatibility issue with xampp so  i deactivated User Account Control
but still i can't output hello world in the browser.
what could be the problem ? 
ps: i already have apache & mysql services running in the xampp control panel

Answer (score 1):

imho, you are typing the full path of your *hello.php* in browsers or may be your *hello.php* is not under *htdocs* or under your web directory..

You need to type something like `http://localhost/hello.php` or `http://127.0.0.1/hello.php`

Comment: thanks it worked. it seems my path to the hello.php was not correct